# InstallShield: cannot extract icon with index 0 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, installshield

Im trying to use installshield to mak an installer for my applicatoin but when I add my icon to it then when i try and build it i get the error message InstallShield: cannot extract icon with index 0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. InstallShield is trying to extract the embedded resource (icon) for Add/Remove Programs and/or a shortcut.  Recompile your EXE to include an icon and the message will go away.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I have done done it with icons I have done it without an icon and even using the default icon and I still seem to get the same error. Really dont get what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I faced something similar. 
You need to check that the exe from which the icon will be extracted is present on the path specified in Shortcut/Folder of Install Shield

Answer (score 0):

The reason I get this message is usually because I have not selected the icon file on the Shortcuts/Folders dialogue:

[image: InstallShield - Shortcuts/Folders]