# Error -3204:Cannot extract icon with index 0 from file

Tags: c#, winforms, installshield-2012

In building an installer for my application,i repeatedly getting an error:

`Error -3204: Cannot extract icon with index 0 from file C:\Users\....`

A quick google search got me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954618/installshield-cannot-extract-icon-with-index-0-vb-net)  (where the issue isn't resolved) and following step by step procedure [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/) enabled me to add   `C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll` everytime i build my project, then selecting `icon:2` .A `setup.exe` is created despite an error
and installs app for me but with no trace in Add/Remove programs in Control Panel.
How to get that icon in Add/Remove Add/Remove programs in Control Panel.

**EDIT:** if there's any other software for windows installer for VS2013 such as SetupProject with the previous releases of VS 2xxx please suggest me

Comment: Put icon in the project folder.

Comment: How can i put an icon from `shell32.dll`?

Comment: I answered you. see the answer

Comment: Is there any alternative for VS2013?

Comment: Yes. There are. I posted them in the answer.

Comment: Regarding your edit, did you mean like [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d)?

Comment: Precisely i need an installer for my app

Comment: And having an issue with the pre-loaded ISL with VS2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the method of creating the setup file. See the link below :

[Clike Here](http://gregchutech.blogspot.com/2014/04/installshield-cannot-extract-icon-with.html)

Update :

Here are two other setup applications which can make setup of your application.

[QSetup](http://www.pantaray.com/qsetup.html)
and [Centurion Setup](http://www.gammadyne.com/centurion.htm)

You can try them to make setup for your application.

Comment: I added one of *.ico file from my system to project folder and added index to 3 .the error isn't leaving me alone

Comment: @CrystalHeart I posted a link there. Go to the link and follow its instructions then you won't see any error.

Comment: Actually,there he tells to create an .ico file and the same i did and changed the index from default('0') to '2' but still no hope

Comment: @CrystalHeart If those two other setup applications helped you so mark this as answered so other who have this same issue can find their answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ISProductFolder>\redist\Language Independent\OS Independent\setupicon.ico
```

When I used the file path above in the project assistant --> application shortcuts section --> use alternate shortcut icon, the basic icon showed up and allowed me to select the icon. Now my project builds without this error.  (the icon looks bad but it works.....)

[IconShow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZcHs.png)